# Semaphore keeps crashing on OS X

Tags: c, macos, semaphore

I have the following code:

```
sem_t *semFull = sem_open("/semFull", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
sem_t *semEmpty = sem_open("/semEmpty", O_CREAT, 0644, shared.buffSize);
```

This piece of code works perfectly on Linux but when I try to execute it on OS X I keep getting segmentation fault

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `sem_t` on OS X, you should use `semaphore_t`.

You need to import the following libraries

```
#include <mach/semaphore.h>
#include <mach/task.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
```

And you can create your semaphores using:

```
semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), &shared.full, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 0);
semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), &shared.empty, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, shared.buffSize);
```

Your problem should be solved using this approach.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I'll try to implement the code you gave me